# Packing folder with Inno Setup compiler

Tags: inno-setup

When I compile the setup file, it adds the files from the `lib` folder, but not the folder itself. See the image. But what I want here is that it should add the `lib` folder as well as the files inside.

My code is

```
Source: "E:\AMS\lib\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the files into a same-named folder:

```
Source: "E:\AMS\lib\*"; DestDir: "{app}\lib"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

---

Note that you obviously expect the Inno Setup to somehow magically determine that the `E:\AMS` is a "root" source folder. And consequently that it should maintain a directory structure below it. But there's no way in Inno Setup to set such root folder. All entries in the `[Files]` section are independent. So even if you have an entry like the one below, it won't change a thing:

```
Source: "E:\AMS\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Comment: thankx bro but what to do if  i only want to add or create an empty folder that contains no files

Comment: for example only lib not its files

Comment: That's what the [`[Dirs]` section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection) is for.