# InnoSetup: Trying to exclude all except one subfolder

Tags: inno-setup

I have an InnoSetup script that is supposed to exclude a subfolder full of other subfolders (>40) **except one** of them.
In the Compiler Output I do see files in this subfolder being compressed but the **installation does not create that folder** nor copies the files from it anywhere else.

The script looks like this:
(The `Release\extra\more\subs` is the folder full of other folders - I'd like to include only the `Release\extra\more\subs\need_this_one`.)

```
[Files]  
; Use all files and folders except some special ones
Source: "Release\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs; Excludes: "more\subs"
; Do use some specific folders
Source: "Release\extra\more\subs\need_this_one\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

The first line should copy all files and folders in `Release` except any subfolders with path matching "`more\subs`" - and it **does** that.

I was under impression that the second line will then copy the `Release\extra\more\subs\need_this_one` subfolder and files in it - **but it does not**.

Does anyone have any idea why is that so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packing folder with Inno Setup compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256122/packing-folder-with-inno-setup-compiler)

Comment: Btw, your question title does not correspond to your actual problem.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl, thanks for pointing it out. The other question is about a folder not being created but files were being copied - in my case the files were not copied. If they were, I'd probably figure it out soon enough.

Comment: OK, while the question itself is not a duplicate, the answer can be applied to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems I'm having a habit of answering my own questions. ;)

The catch was that `DestDir` needs the path on top of `{app}` to know where to put the files.

So, the script that works would be:

```
[Files]  
; Use all files and folders except some special ones
Source: "Release\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs; Excludes: "more\subs"
; Do use some specific folders
Source: "Release\extra\more\subs\need_this_one\*"; DestDir: "{app}\extra\more\subs\need_this_one"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

It does makes sense, although it is not clear why, without the path, it did not simply copy files from `need_this_one` into `{app}`  ...